# How to add items to a JComboBox from a List of Objects

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently trying to create a `JComboBox` that shows me the name of different car components. The `Component` class is currently with the following variables:

```
public class Component{
     private int id;
     private String name;
     private double price;
     private int quantity; 
     private String type;
```

}

Now I have another class that contains all the components that exist, which have been loaded from my Database:

```
public class Stand{
     private List<Component> allComponents;
     
     public Stand(){
     //loads the components from my database into allComponents
     this.allComponents = componentDAO.loadComponents();


     public List<Componente> getAllComponents(){
        return this.allComponents;
     }
}
```

What I'm looking for now is to create a class called `SelectComponent` with some `JComboBox` that show me only the name of each `Component` as an option. How would I do that?

Also, after selecting the desired `Component`, I would have another `List<Component>` in this same class to keep the selected Components, since I will need to have more than one JComboBox in the same window. How do I add the selected `Component` to this `List` after it being selected?

If you can set the JComboBox to already show the components for a certain type, for example "Paint", would be even better since I would need help with that too. Please let me know if there's more information I need to provide. I have some difficulty in keeping track on everything that's needed since there's already a lot more done. Just trying to get an idea and apply it to my program.

Comment: Don't call your class `Component`. There is already an AWT class by then name. Make you class name more descriptive, maybe `CarComponent` to avoid confusion.

Comment: `If you can set the JComboBox to already show the components for a certain type,` - well you just check the "type" of the CarComponent before you add the object to the combo box.

Answer (score 2):

> show me only the name of each Component as an option.

Create custom renderer to display the "name" property.

The code for a basic renderer would be something like:

```
class CarComponentRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer
{
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        if (value instanceof CarComponent)
        {
            CarComponent carComponent = (CarComponent)value;
            setText( carComponent.getName() );
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

You then set the renderer on the combo box using:

```
comboBox.setRenderer( new CarComponentRenderer() );
```

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information and a more complete solution.

Comment: Could you also help me with the creating of the JComboBox and further use of the custom renderer?

Comment: @JoãoAmorim, see edit showing how to use the renderer.

Comment: @JoãoAmorim, don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

If you override `toString()` method (like below code) in your `Component` class, you can show Component's name in the combo box even without having to write a custom renderer.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
  return this.name;
}
```

Comment: never-ever override toString for application reasons.. a custom renderer is the way to go